# How to implement Answering Machine detection using Twiml or twilio JSClient

Tags: twilio

We are building an in-browser messenger app using Twilio, From JS client we make a call and use Twiml to dial the number, This is our basic flow. I understand from other Questions that AMD is only available for RestAPI, How can I utilise Rest API along with JS client, or How can I Integrate AMD with my current setup. any help/suggestions Please :) .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes as far as I know you can't use TwiML to turn on the answer machine detection and you are restricted to using the API.

The API endpoint you want to use is the *Call Resource*. This is in essence not nothing more than a `POST` to `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls.json` and then you set the parameter `MachineDetection` to `Enable` (please refer to the docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#create-a-call-resource)).

But this needs authentication in form of your `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` which you can't expose to any client. I don't know the details of your JS client and how you do authentication & authorisation but I'd suggest you encapsulate the logic in your backend where you can properly secure it. Then you can also use the Twilio helper libraries, e.g. for Python or Node.JS, to place the call (example for Node.JS taken from the docs and adapted):

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
  .create({
     twiml: '<Response><Say>Hello World!</Say></Response>',
     to: '+1...',
     from: '+1...',
     machineDetection: 'Enable'
   })
  .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

Comment: You may also want to use a Twilio Conference to bind the two legs together, depending on how the call is initiated (does the client initiate the call and thus use a conference to place the Twilio client into) or do you make the REST API call and then when answered, call the client using a `<Dial><Client>`.

Comment: Iam using https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device this.

Comment: @Alan Client initiates the call and I use <dial> verb to dial the number

Comment: So use conference, to connect the two legs. Agent calls into conference and then call customer using /Calls resource with AMD and then connect them to same conference.